# I am trying to print all pythagorian triplets till nn and getting error :parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) in funcp

Tags: haskell

I am trying to print all Pythagorean triplets in haskell and while the logic is correct, i get error in parsing in line: `funcp :: Int Int Int -> IO ()` . Can someone help me find the issue? I am very new to haskell

```
checkp :: Int->Int-> IO()
    checkp nn m= do
        let n=1
            if n<m
                then funcp m n nn 
                else checkp nn (m+1)
    funcp :: Int Int Int -> IO ()
```

Comment: @WillNess no it just says this:
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
7 |     funcp :: Int Int Int -> IO ()

Comment: I've posted an answer by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong indentation:

```
checkp :: Int->Int-> IO()
    checkp nn m= do
        let n=1
```

here:

```
  --        *
            if n<m
                then funcp m n nn 
                else checkp nn (m+1)
```

while your error probably points you to the following statement after that:

```
    funcp :: Int Int Int -> IO () 
    ....
```

Syntactically, this `if` must start at the same column as the preceding line, namely here, `let`.

For more, check out the "do notation".

Of course the following is also an indentation error, at the very start of your code:

```
checkp :: Int->Int-> IO()
    checkp nn m= do
--  ^^^
```

They too must start at the same indentation level.

Comment: Thank You so much, this helps tremendously!

Comment: glad to help. :)